# Stringholics algorithm

Tags: c++

The following is the link to the problem I am trying.
https://www.interviewbit.com/problems/stringoholics/

My code worked well for simple case given in the link.

```
//function to compute gcd
long long int gcd(long long int a, long long int b)
{
    if (b == 0)
        return a;
    return gcd(b, a % b);
}

//function to compute LCM
long long int findlcm(vector<long long int> a)
{

    long long int ans = a[0];

    // ans contains LCM of arr[0], ..arr[i]
    // after i'th iteration,
    for (int i = 1; i < a.size(); i++)
        ans = ((((a[i] % 1000000007 * ans % 1000000007))) % 1000000007 / (gcd(a[i] % 1000000007, ans % 1000000007)));

    return ans % 1000000007;
}

//function to solve given problem
int solve(vector<string>& A)
{

    vector<long long int> a; //vetor to store no.of rotations requireda

    for (int i = 0; i < A.size(); i++) {

        long long int j = 1; //variable to keep track of no.of rotations

        string curr = A[i]; //original ith string

        long long int n = curr.length(); //length of  ith string

        // leftrotatio of string by 1 element
        rotate(A[i].begin(), A[i].begin() + j, A[i].end());

        //to check if modifies string is same as original
        if (A[i] == curr)
            a.push_back(j);

        else {
            while (A[i] != curr) {

                rotate(A[i].begin(), A[i].begin() + (j + 1) % n, A[i].end());
                j++;
            }

            a.push_back(j + 1);
        } //pushing no.of rotations for ith element
    }

    long long int c = findlcm(a);
    return (int)(c);
}
```

Input:

```
A : [ "aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa",
      "babaaaabbaba",
      "baaaaababaabbaaaaabbbbbbbaabbaaaababbabaababaabaaabbbaaaaa",
      "abaabb",
      "aababbbbabbaaaabbaaaaaaaababbbabbbbaabbaabaabbaabaababbbababaababaabbababaaabaaaab",
      "babaaaaababbbbbabbbbabbaaabaaaababbabbaabbbabbaaaabbbabaaaabaaaababb",
      "bbbbbbaaaaaabbbbbbababaabaabbbbbaaabbabbaabbbbaaaaaababbabaaabbabbabbbabbaabbabbbbaabbbaaaaabbabaaab",
      "aabaaabaabbbbababbabbabaaaababbababbbabbbbaabbaaaaababbbbbababbbbaaababababab",
      "aaaababbbaabbbabaabb",
      "ababaaaabbabbbbaaabbababbbabbbabaaa",
      "aaabaabbbabaa",
      "baababbababbbbbabbabaabbabbbbbaaaabaaaababaa",
      "babaa",
      "abbabababbbbbbbbbbbaaaaaababbababaaabbbaaaabbbababbabaabbaabbbbaabbbaabbababababaabaaabbaaabbba",
      "ababbaabbaaabbbabaabababbbabaaabbbaababaaa",
      "abbaaaababbbbaaabaaaabaaaaabaababbabbaababbbabbbbbbbbbabbaabaaabbaaababbbaa",
      "bbabababaabbabbabbbabbaababbabaaabbbababab",
      "abbbaaabaab",
      "bbaaabbaaabbaabbabababa",
      "aabaabaaaaaaabaabbbaaababbbbbbababbaabababbaaaaabbabbbabbbaababbaabababbbbbbbbbaabaab",
      "babbaaabbabbaabaaabbb",
      "bbabaabba",
      "baabaaaaabbaaaaaabbbbaaaabababa",
      "babbaababaaba",
      "baabaabaabbababbaabbabbbbbabaaaabbbbbabbabbbbbabbbabaabbbbabbbbaaabbbbabababaaaababbaaabbabb",
      "abbbbaaaabaabbabbaababaabbababbbaaabbabbbbbaaabbabbaabbb",
      "bababaaaaabababbabbaabababbbaabbaabaabaabbabbbababbaaabababbababbbb",
      "abaaabbbabbbaabba",
      "bbbbaaaabbbababaabbbababaaaababbaaaaaabbbabbaababababbba",
      "bababaabaaaabbaabbababbaabbaabaabbaaaaaaaababbaaaaaabbaaabaabaaababbababbbbaabbabbabaabab",
      "aabbbabaaabababaabbbbaabbabaaabbbaaabbabbbbabaabbbbaabbbaaaaabbbabbbbb",
      "aabbbbbbabaabbbabbaababbababaabaaababbbbabbbaababaaaabbaaabaaabaaaabbbabababbab",
      "abaaaaababbabaabbbaaaaabbaaaabaaaaaaaababbaabbbaabbabbbabbaaaaaab",
      "bbbaabbabbbbbbaaaabbabbbbbbbaaabaababbaaaabbbaababbaaabbbbbbbbabbabababbaaabaabaaabaaaabbbbbabaabaaa",
      "bbaaabaaabaaabaabaaabbaabaabbabaabaabbababaaaaabaabbbbaba",
      "abaababaaabbabaabaabbbaaabbaabababbabaaabbbbabbbbbaaaaa",
      "abba",
      "abbbababbaaabbaaabbbabaabbababaaabbbbaaaaababbabbaabbabbbaaabaabbaaaaabaaaabbbaabbbabbbbbbbabb",
      "bbabbaaabaaaabbaaaabbbaaaababbbaabaaaaab",
      "abbaabaabbaaaaaaaabbaabbabbababaaaaaaabbabaabaabbbabbaabbaababbaabbaba",
      "bbbbaababbaaaaaaaaabbbabbbabaabababaababaababa",
      "baaabaabbbbbbaabbabbbabaaaaababaabaababbbaaaaaaaabbbbbabbabaaaaaaaabababaabaababaaabbaaaaaaaaabaa",
      "aababbbabbaaaaababbabaababbbbbbbbaaabbaaaaabbaabbbba",
      "ababababaaaaaabbbabbaaababaabb",
      "bababbaababaabbbabbaab",
      "baababababbaaaaabbbbbbbbbaabababb",
      "bbbbb",
      "aabaabbbaabababbababaaaaabbbbaababaabbabbbbbbaabbaaabbababbbabbabbbaabbbab",
      "bbaabbbbaabbaaaaaabbbaabababbbaabaaabbbbbabaababbbaababbbaaabaaabaaaababbbbaabbaababb",
      "aaababbaaaaabaabababbabaabbbbabbaba" ];
```

Actual result: `423191921`
Expected result: `487555988`

Comment: A hint, people here do not really like following links. Providing the link to the full background is good. But you need to explain yourself and directly here. Among other things that allows to spot the cause of any problem/mistake in your (mis-)understanding of the big picture.

Comment: If you show code (which is good), try to follow this concept [mre]. Only if you follow it, a mistake in your code can be found. Experience shows that in too many of the cases "here is the code in which I believe the error must be" the error is finally found - elsewhere.

Comment: Please explain the Expected result, especially if only with this large input you have a problem. If not please show smaller input which reproduces the problem.

Comment: It's not so much a hatred of following links as it is the loss of information when the link rots. A few months from now the question may be weakened or rendered useless by a non-functional link or a change in content at the link.

Comment: I see now that the problem is quite long to even summarize, that relativates my first comment. You should however still explain your approach to solving it, i.e. your algorithm. I see that you try the math path, instead of simulating, which is good.

Comment: @user4581301 I agree with you. However (see me previous comment) this is a rather extreme case, as far as I have yet seen...

Comment: For readability, please reformat your code for fewer empty lines and consistent indentation. Maybe also reformat the example input, it currently is an offputting wall of text. I guess that one input string per line would be less so and might help with seeing patterns.

Comment: I did follow the link after all. But what I am missing is a definition of the function prototype to use. Yours is convincing, but is it somewhere defined in the challenge?

Comment: @user4581301 I, for one, *do* hate following links.  In a fortunate coincidence, quelling my hatred for following links in the immediacy also prevents the link-rot of the future.

Comment: Is there a string pattern that matches the original after `n` rotations where `n` isn't a factor of the string length? I have a feeling there might be?

Comment: No its not possible.For first time we rotate by 1 elment ,second time we rotate by 2,third time 3 and so on .For nth time we rotate by n elements.So no.of rotations after n times is sum of first n natural numers i.e.,n*(n+1)/2.So no.of rotations is alwzys a factor of n.

Comment: The problem statement is unclear. It appears to say that after a string is cycled to its original self, the next operation cycles it by 1 character again, but this does not agree with the way the operation is defined.

Comment: And n must be equal to multiple of string length to get original string.

Comment: Please vote for this question.So that more people can view this and may find a solution.

Comment: `rotate` -  can't you compare Fibonacci numbers with the length of the string?

Comment: `rotate(A[i].begin(), A[i].begin() + (j + 1) % n, A[i].end())` should be `rotate(A[i].begin(), A[i].begin() + 1, A[i].end())`, I still dont get your desired answer though

Comment: You don't need ever to really rotate the string. Just sum the count of rotations and see if the length of the string is dividable by it. Like 99% of online coding challenges is _not_ to do take the obvious approach.

Comment: j+1 is the right one.Because no.of elements by which we rotate the string is incremented in each iteration.It follows the sequence 1,2,3,4 etc so we need a variable instead of a constant.@Alan Birtles

Comment: Yeah you are right that is the effecient approach.But Im stucked with this approach.@Kamil Cuk

Comment: @KamilCuk the length is not enough, "aaaa" and "aaab" have different periods.

Comment: Right right. So the first algorithm you need is "reduce" - strings like `bababa` can be reduced to `ba` - the substring `ba` repeats itself. It's actually easy to write - extract substring from the string foreach length len/2 to 1, search string until the end is reached for substrings. If the string consist solely of substrings  - you can handle just the substring not the string itself.

Comment: the first problem which you can directly notice: consider test case: "aaaa". You are storing 1 into your answer but instead, you should not add anything because not of rotations required  is 0.

Answer (score -2):

I think you have to take the modulo inverse of gcd and then multiply the result with it and then save in ans variable because division in modulo arithmetic is done by taking modulo inverse.